# Giving constant inside greater than function or in raster calculator

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

```
threshold=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

stream=GreaterThanEqual(facc_clip,threshold)
```

> Error: Input Raster: Dataset 570416 does not exist or is not supported

Here 570416 is the value I input in the script tool, why is this error happening, I can replace threshold with 570416 and it works, but I want each time this to be an user input

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: At the moment you're only presenting a copy/paste from your code. I can tell that because you're only showing us your third parameter.  Are you doing this with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcMap?  What data type are you using for the parameter?

Comment: Make it float(arcpy.Para....)

Answer (score 1):

`threshold` is a string because you use arcpy.GetParameterAs*Text*. So your expression is actually `stream=GreaterThanEqual(facc_clip, "570416")` and because "570416" is text, arcpy looks for a raster with the name "570416".

You need to convert the text to a number, either with the `int` or `float` functions e.g.

```
threshold = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
```